# How to prioritise some points over others using curve fit from SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to model the following curve:

[image]

To perform it, I'm using curve_fit from SciPy, fitting an exponential function.

```
def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * b**(c*x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, y, p0=(1,2,2), 
                       bounds=((0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)))
```

When I first do it, I get this:

[image]

Which is minimising the residuals, each point with the same level of importance. 
What I want, is to get a curve that gives more importance to the last values of the curve (from x-axis 30, for example) than to the first values, so it fits better in the end of the curve than in the beginning of it.

I know that from here there are many ways to approach this (first of all, define what is the importance that I want to give to each of the residuals). My question here, is to get some idea of how to approach this.

One idea that I had, is to change the sigma value to weight each data point by its inverse value.

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, y, p0=(1,2,2), 
                       bounds=((0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)),
                       sigma=1/y)
```

In this case, I get something like I was looking for:

[image]

It doesn't look bad, but I'm looking for another way of doing this, so that I can "control" each of the data points, like to weight each of the residuals in a linear way, or exponential, or even choosing it manually (rather than all of them by the inverse, as in the previous case).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide your dataset?

Comment: Yes. These are the data points for the blue curve: `y = [155,229,322,453,655,888,1128,1694,2036,2502,3089,3858,4636,5883,7375,9172,10149,12462,12462,17660,21157,24747,27980,31506,35713,41035,47021,53578,59138,63927,69176]`.
The points of the red curve, are the ones from the model, which I get them like this:
`np.array( (popt[0]) * popt[1]**(x*popt[2]) )`.
Being x, an array from 1 to the length of y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that there's no need for three coefficients. Since

```
a * b**(c*x) = a * exp(log(b)*c*x).
```

we can define `k = log(b)*c`.

Here's a suggestion how you could tackle your problem *by hands* with [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) and a priority vector:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def exponenial_func2(x, a, k):
    return a * np.exp(k*x)

# returns the vector of residuals
def fitwrapper2(coeffs, *args):
    xdata, ydata, prio = args
    return prio*(exponenial_func2(xdata, *coeffs)-ydata)

# Data
n = 31
xdata = np.arange(n)
ydata = np.array([155.0,229,322,453,655,888,1128,1694,
                  2036,2502,3089,3858,4636,5883,7375,
                  9172,10149,12462,12462,17660,21157,
                  24747,27980,31506,35713,41035,47021,
                  53578,59138,63927,69176])

# The priority vector
prio = np.ones(n)
prio[-1] = 5

res = least_squares(fitwrapper2, x0=[1.0,2.0], bounds=(0,np.inf), args=(xdata,ydata,prio))
```

- With `prio[-1] = 5` we give the last point a high priority.
- `res.x` contains your optimal coefficients. Here `a, k = res.x`.
- Note that for `prio = np.ones(n)` it's a normal least squares fitting (like curve_fit does) where all points have the same *priority*.

You can control the priority of each point by increasing its value in the `prio` array. Comparing both results gives me:

[image]